# CFA lavaan Interpreting NA standardized residuals

Tags: r, confirmatory-factor, lavaan

I am implementing CFA at the moment and looking at the residuals of model to determine how to improve the model fit
When i take the raw scores from the model, i get residuals for everything
When i take a look at the standardized/z-score residuals, I can see `NA` between some of the questions which have large residuals in the raw score

I would like to examine the standardized residuals because i know those residuals are statistically significant at 1.96 (p<0.05) and 2.58(p<0.01)
Can anyone explain to me why the null values exist?

Below is a reproducible example where `x3` and `x2` have raw residual scores of 0.126 but when i standardize them i get `NA`

```
# Stackoverflow Question
library(lavaan)

mydf <- HolzingerSwineford1939

# First Create the CFA model for both groups combined
HS.model <- ' visual  =~ x1 + x2 + x3
textual =~ x4 + x5 + x6'


# Fit the model Standardizing on the latent variable
fit <- cfa(HS.model, data = mydf, meanstructure = TRUE, std.lv = TRUE, estimator = 'MLR')

# Get the standardized residuals
res_raw <- residuals(fit, type = 'raw')$cov

# Get the standardized residuals
res <- residuals(fit, type = 'standardized')$cov
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you check the documentation for `lavaan-class`, you will see a reference to [Standardized Residuals in Mplus](http://www.statmodel.com/download/StandardizedResiduals.pdf). This document explains how the normalized and standardized residuals computed in Mplus and I think `lavaan` follows Mplus in this computation (see documentation of lavaan-class:  "For more information about the normalized and standardized residuals, see the Mplus reference below.")

According to this document, the standardized mean residual is

$$\frac{m_i-\hat \mu_i}{\sqrt{Var(m_i-\hat \mu_i)}}$$

and the standardized covariance residual is

$$\frac{s_{ij}-\hat \sigma_{ij}}{\sqrt{Var(s_{ij}-\hat \sigma_{ij})}}.$$

And in both cases, Hausman's theorem is used for the calculation of variance, so

$$\begin{align} Var(m_i-\hat \mu_i) &= Var(m_i) -Var(\hat \mu_i) \\ Var(s_{ij}-\hat \sigma_{ij}) &= Var(s_{ij}) -Var(\hat \sigma_{ij}).
\end{align}$$

At the end of the document, it is explained that

> One problem with Hausman’s (1978) approach to computing the residual variance is that sometimes the variance estimates given by [the above equations] can be negative. In that case the standardized residual is not computed and Mplus prints 999. Typically in such situation the normalized residual can be used.

Similarly, `lavaan` returns `NA`. It is also recommended in `lavaan` documentation to use normalized residuals.